# Why is the "B" code not printing the required range?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I'm trying to make a function to print a range of numbers. the "A" code runs correctly but the "b" code only prints "50"

## (A) correctly print 50, 60, 70,80,90, 100

```
for i in range (50,110,10):
    print(i)
```

## (B) print 50 only

```
def rest(rmin,rmax,intervals):
    for i in range(rmin,rmax,intervals):
       return i
print(rest(50,110,10))
```

Comment: you `return i` causing the loop to stop. you probably only want to `print(i)`.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the following code for accomplishing what you are trying to do:

```
>>> for integer in range(50, 110, 10):
    print(integer)


50
60
70
80
90
100
>>> def rest(minimum, maximum, interval):
    for integer in range(minimum, maximum, interval):
        yield integer


>>> print(*rest(50, 110, 10), sep='\n')
50
60
70
80
90
100
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks!! this helped